# Why is BehaviorSubject not working for me in Angular 13?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import {BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalService {
  private display: BehaviorSubject<'open' | 'close'> = new BehaviorSubject('close');

  watch(): Observable<'open' | 'close'> {
    return this.display.asObservable();
  }

  open() {
    this.display.next('open');
  }

  close() {
    this.display.next('close');
  }
}
```

> Error: src/app/services/modal.service.ts:9:11 - error TS2322: Type
> 'BehaviorSubject<"close">' is not assignable to type
> 'BehaviorSubject<"open" | "close">'.   Types of property 'observers'
> are incompatible.
> Type 'Observer<"close">[]' is not assignable to type 'Observer<"open" | "close">[]'.
> Type 'Observer<"close">' is not assignable to type 'Observer<"open" | "close">'.
> Type '"open" | "close"' is not assignable to type '"close"'.
> Type '"open"' is not assignable to type '"close"'.

https://betterprogramming.pub/create-a-modal-for-your-angular-app-without-libs-671bd7280867

This article shows Modal working in Angular but I am having trouble with this.

Comment: This is working fine on my end, but it appears you are assigning ```BehaviorSubject``` to ```Subject```, could this be the problem?

Comment: @OvidijusParsiunas what version of Angular did you use?

Comment: ```^10.2.2``` and rxjs version of ```^6.6.3```

Comment: This is a type validation issue.
You are trying to assign a behavior subject to subject

Answer (score 3):

It is a type validation issue

change

```
private display: BehaviorSubject<'open' | 'close'> = new BehaviorSubject('close');
```

to

```
private display: BehaviorSubject<'open' | 'close'> = new BehaviorSubject<'open' | 'close'>('close');
```

and all will be aligned.

Comment: I agree, this should solve your problem, you can infer type though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
private display = new BehaviorSubject<'open' | 'close'>('close');
```

*Basically what Fabio said is right, but you might as well let Typescript infer the type. Defining it twice is redundant.*